# Akka: What jar file contains jdocs.AbstractJavaTest?

Tags: akka

What jar-file dependency do I add to resolve this import?

```
import jdocs.AbstractJavaTest;
```

It's imported in Akka's own example code (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/testing.html) yet after a lot of searching I can't find any mention of the actual jar dependency and the Akka documentation search function is so unhelpful that it claims there are no mentions of "jdocs.AbstractJavaTest" even when the code is on the screen in front of me.

Note that the following artifacts do not contain it:

```
'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.5.6'
'com.typesafe.akka:akka-testkit_2.12:2.5.3'
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`AbstractJavaTest`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.6/akka-docs/src/test/java/jdocs/AbstractJavaTest.scala) is located in the *akka-docs* module in the Akka repository and is not packaged in any of the published jars. All it does is extend `JUnitSuite`:

```scala
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2016-2017 Lightbend Inc. <http://www.lightbend.com>
 */
package jdocs

import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitSuite

/**
 * Base class for all runnable example tests written in Java
 */
abstract class AbstractJavaTest extends JUnitSuite {

}
```

As documented in the [pull request](https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/19768#r52847973) that brought in this class, it was added to (1) hide the detail that the Java test suites in the Akka documentation need to extend `JUnitSuite`, and (2) to define that in one location. Feel free to manually add this class or its equivalent to your code, or simply have your test suites directly extend `JUnitSuite`.

Comment: Seems as if the [official Akka Testing](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/testing.html) page currently skips this fact.

Comment: Update. It might help another person.

org.scalatest.junit.JUnitSuite has been renamed or moved to org.scalatestplus.junit.JUnitSuite;

to import using Gradle as of July 2021, use this line. 
compile group: 'org.scalatestplus', name: 'junit-4-12_2.13', version: '3.3.0.0-SNAP2'

Comment: Once you import the right jar, examples posted in FlowDocTest.java run well.

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html
direct link: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.6.15/akka-docs/src/test/java/jdocs/stream/FlowDocTest.java